# Vue rendering order

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am Working on creating a tab component with vue and noticed the following behavior.

If I create my component like this:

```
<tabs-component>
  <tab-component :title="1">
    <h1>1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </tab-component>
  <tab-component :title="2">
    <h1>2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </tab-component>
</tabs-component>
```

Life hooks are triggered in this order:

- Tabs component created
- Tab component created
- Tab component mounted
- Tabs component mounted

Which seems to be the correct behavior however, if instead of declaring the slots manually I use a `v-for` directive assuming I am dealing with some data from a service like this:

```
<tabs-component>
  <tab-component v-for="(type, index) in beerTypes" :key="type.slug" :title="type.slug">
    <h1>{{ index }}</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </tab-component>
</tabs-component>
```

Life hooks are triggered in this order:

- Tabs component created
- Tabs component mounted
- Tab component created
- Tab component mounted

The `v-for` directive seems to be messing with the order life hooks are triggered. And this is causing me trouble since I am firing the `selectTab` method on the mounted life hook to pick the default tab selected, but when is triggered tabs have not been mounted.

Does any one know how I can correctly listen for the events in the right order, or wait for the child components to be ready so I can pick the default panel?

Here is the rest of my code for reference:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <main>
    <h1>Discover beer styles</h1>
    <tabs-component>
      <tab-component v-for="(type, index) in beerTypes" :key="type.slug" :title="type.slug">
        <h1>{{ index }}</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </tab-component>
    </tabs-component>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios';
  import TabsComponent from './components/tabs/Tabs.vue';
  import TabComponent from './components/tabs/Tab.vue';

  export default {
    components: {
      'tabs-component': TabsComponent,
      'tab-component': TabComponent,
    },

    data() {
      return {
        beerTypes: null,
        selectedType: null
      }
    },

    filters: {
      capitalize: function(value) {
        if (!value) return '';

        return `${value.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${value.slice(1)}`;
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      axios.get('/data/data.json')
        .then((response) => {
          this.beerTypes = response.data;
          this.selectedType = this.beerTypes[0].slug;
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    },

    methods: {
      selectActiveType: function(selected) {
        this.selectedType = selected;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

***Tabs.vue***

```
<template>
  <div class="tabs-component">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :class="{'is-active': tab.isActive}" :key="index">
          <a href="#" @click="selectTab(index)">{{ tab.title }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <slot/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        tabs: [],
        activeTabIndex: 0
      }
    },

    created() {
      this.tabs = this.$children;
    },

    mounted() {
      this.selectTab(this.activeTabIndex);
    },

    methods: {
      selectTab(index) {
        this.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
          tab.isActive = (this.tabs.indexOf(tab) === index);
        }.bind(this));
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

***Tab.vue***

```
<template>
  <section v-show="isActive">
    <slot/>
  </section>
</template>
```

I appreciate if someone could take the time to help me.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that your service call is asynchronous and that is the reason that when App.vue is initialized there's no data within beerTypes and so tab-component doesn't get rendered and so life cycle hooks of tabs-component are initialized first. Please tell if the above case is the scenario.

Comment: Hello @AyushGupta, when the app is mounted I am using axios to call a JSON file that provides the info. Added to the question the fragment of code that performs that call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think uses [Vue: provide/inject](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject) will be one solution at here.

For your case, if new `<tab-component>` is added (you stated beerTypes will be updated from your backend service), `<tabs-component>`  will not know unless get newest `this$children` inside hook=`updated()`.

If use **provide/inject**, we can let `<tab-component>` register its intance to one data property of `<tabs-components>`. Then `<tabs-component>` will not need to care about new tab is added, and is able to access the instance of `<tab-component>` directly.

Also you should implement one `_unRegister`, when the instance is destroied, remove it from the data property of `<tabs-component>`, below demo uses hook=`beforeDestory` to implement it.

Below is one dmeo:

```js
Vue.productionTip = false
Vue.component('tabs-component', {
  template: `  <div class="tabs-component">
    <div>
      <h3>Selected Tab: {{activeTabIndex}}</h3>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :class="{'is-active': tab.isActive}" :key="index">
          <a href="#" @click="selectTab(index)">{{ tab.title }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <slot/>
    </div>
  </div>`,
  provide () {
    return {
      _tabs: this
    }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        tabs: [],
        activeTabIndex: 0
      }
    },
    mounted() {

    },

    methods: {
      selectTab(selectedIndex) {
        this.activeTabIndex = selectedIndex
        this.tabs.forEach((tab, tabIndex) => {
          tab.isActive = selectedIndex === tabIndex
        })
      },
      _registerTab(tab) {
        this.tabs.push(tab)
        this.selectTab(this.activeTabIndex)
      },
      _unRegisterTab(unRegTab) {
        this.tabs = this.tabs.filter(tab=>{
          return unRegTab !== tab
        })
        this.selectTab(0)
      }
    }
})

Vue.component('tab-component', {
  template: `  <section v-show="isActive" :title="title">
    <slot/>
  </section>`,
    inject: {
    _tabs: {
      default () {
        console.error('tab-component must be child of tab-components')
      }
        }
  },
  props: ['title'],
  mounted () {
    this._tabs._registerTab(this)
  },
  beforeDestroy(){
    this._tabs._unRegisterTab(this)
  },
  data () {
    return {
      isActive: false
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      beerTypes: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    pushData () {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.beerTypes.push({'slug': 'test' + this.beerTypes.length})
      }, 1000)
    },
    popData () {
      this.beerTypes.pop()
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.is-active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="pushData()">Add Tab</button>
  <button @click="popData()">Pop one</button>
    <tabs-component>
      <tab-component v-for="(type, index) in beerTypes" :key="type.slug" :title="type.slug">
        <h1>{{ index }}: {{type.slug}}</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </tab-component>
    </tabs-component>
</div>
```

And pay an attention on this note in the Vue guide for **provide/inject**:

> Note: the provide and inject bindings are NOT reactive. This is
> intentional. However, if you pass down an observed object, properties
> on that object do remain reactive.

Comment: If you were to add the ability to set a tab as active with a prop or set the first tab by default if no tab has the active prop is there a way to wait until all of them are registered so you can make that decision?

Comment: `is there a way to wait until all of them are registered so you can make that decision?` we should treat each registration as final registration. That means you can add some logics inside `_registerTab`, based on current activeIndex or someelse to re-calculate each one should be active or not.

Comment: Thanks for the time to such a complete answer.